# s3 cloudfront listing all contents in bucket to anonymous users

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Anonymous Users can browse to our public distributions or s3 folders and view a list (xml) of all files.

We have set read permissions. Can anyone recommend how to prevent users from viewing the list of files in the bucket, while still allowing them to access and download individual files

Thanks

Dom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the public read access on the bucket but allowing public read on the individual files should block listing the files but still allow the files to be available to anonymous users.